# Why does request.POST always contains name of the button? How to avoid it?

Tags: python, html, django

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        {% load static %}
        <script src="{% static 'jquery-3.6.2.min.js' %}" ></script>
        <script src="{% static 'jquery.js' %}" ></script>
    </head>



    <body>
        <form action="{% url 'index' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button name="button1">button1</button>
            <button name="button2">button2</button>
            <input type="text" name="textbox">
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Every time I type some text in the textbox, let's say I type: "hi" and hit enter, the request.POST returns:

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['FX1qFNzbQUX3fYzAwW27cOu83omLzifnlLU5X0WXXVdOiyNretM5b3VgsGy1OogA'], 'button1': [''], 'textbox': ['hi']}>
```

Why does request.POST contain `'button1': ['']` even though I haven't clicked on it?

Is there a way to avoid request.POST to have `'button1': ['']`?

Comment: Just found a way to avoid getting button name in the request.POST when submitting text. I just put the text box in a separate <form>

Answer (score 1):

Remove a `name` attribute from your `<button>` tag if you don't need to know which buttons is pressed by a user:

```
<form action="{% url 'index' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <button>button1</button>
  <button>button2</button>
</form>
```

As the button is an input as well and can contain name and value.

---

Alternatively you may use the feature to implement the following approach if you wish to vary your backend logic dependant of which button is pressed:

**In a template file:**

```
<form action="{% url 'index' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <button name="action" value="button1_pressed">button1</button>
  <button name="action" value="button2_pressed">button2</button>
</form>
```

**In your views.py:**

```
if request.method == "POST":
    back = reverse('index')
    action = request.POST.get("action")

    if action == "button1_pressed":
        # do something
        messages.success(request, "Successed!")
        return redirect(back)

    if action == "button2_pressed":
        # do something else
        messages.success(request, "Successed!")
        return redirect(back)
```

Comment: I did as you said. The request.POST still contains `'action': ['button1_pressed']` when I submit the text from the textbox

Comment: That's my fault, I'm sorry. Misunderstood the question. I have corrected my answer: You can remove "name" attribute from the button.

Answer (score 0):

you may Try

```
<!--base.html--> 
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <script src="{% static 'jquery-3.6.2.min.js' %}" ></script>
        <script src="{% static 'jquery.js' %}" ></script>
    </head>



    <body>
{% block content %}
        <form action="{% url 'index' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
           <input type="text" name="textbox">
            <button name="button1">button1</button>
            <button name="button2">button2</button>
 
        </form>

{% endblock %}
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried that too, but I still get the button name in the request.POST even though I don't click it.